# Intepretation of -x and -a flags in ps command

Tags: linux, process, ps

According to the [`man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) page of `ps` command, the `x` flag

> Lift the BSD-style "must have a tty" restriction, which is
>                 imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style
>                 (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality
>                 setting is BSD-like.  The set of processes selected in this
>                 manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by
>                 other means.  An alternate description is that this option
>                 causes ps to list all processes owned by you (same EUID as
>                 ps), or to list all processes when used together with the a
>                 option.

and for `-a` flag:

> -a     Select all processes except both session leaders (see
>                 getsid(2)) and processes not associated with a terminal.

In my `Ubunbtu 16.04` laptop:

```
$ ps -a | wc -l
132
/etc/systemd/system
$ ps -x | wc -l
113
```

Does this mean I have 132 processes associated with a terminal (and **not** session leaders at the same time)? How can this be since I have only one `terminator` instance open (and this with only one terminal window running just some commands)?

Can anyone elaborate a bit on the difference among `-x` and `-a` flags?

We all know that to get **all** the processes running we need to combine those two but what is their exact difference?

Comment: Did you mean the BSD option `a` or the UNIX option `-a`. On my system, the former lists all the processes listed by the later, and also session leaders.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some confusion between Unix-style and BSD-style options. The options involving `a` and `x` are `-a` (Unix-style), `a` (BSD-style), and `x` (BSD-style); there is no `-x`. Since you used the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag I’ll concentrate on the `ps` implementation commonly found on Linux distributions.

By default, `ps` only lists the invoking user’s processes which are attached to the current terminal.

`a` lifts the “invoking user” restriction: `ps a` lists all users’ processes which are attached to a terminal. `x` lifts the “attached to a terminal” restriction: `ps x` lists all the invoking user’s processes. `ps ax` lists all processes.

`ps -a` lists all users’ processes which are attached to a terminal and aren’t session leaders.

`ps -ax` is equivalent to `ps ax`: the presence of the `-x` flag, which is BSD-style, causes `ps` to interpret all flags in BSD style. Likewise, `ps -x` is equivalent to `ps x`.

Comment: For the audience - consider to read [What does '-x' mean in the context of the 'ps' command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701577/what-does-x-mean-in-the-context-of-the-ps-command) for complement the current information. Just 2 cents