# What does '-x' mean in the context of the 'ps' command?

Tags: ps, options

If is executed `ps x` (observe there is **no** `-`) then the output is as follows:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2489 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
 2490 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
 2517 tty1     S+     0:00 -bash
 3830 tty4     S      0:00 -bash
 4085 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/0
 4086 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 4184 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/1
 4185 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
 4265 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/2
 4266 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
 4385 tty4     S+     0:00 man ps
 4395 tty4     S+     0:00 pager
 4805 pts/1    S+     0:00 man ps
 4815 pts/1    S+     0:00 pager
 4827 pts/0    S+     0:00 less
 4829 pts/2    R+     0:00 ps x
```

Until here all fine and is expected.

Just playing was executed `ps -x` (observe there is `-`) then the output is as follows:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2489 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
 2490 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
 2517 tty1     S+     0:00 -bash
 3830 tty4     S      0:00 -bash
 4085 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/0
 4086 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 4184 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/1
 4185 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
 4265 ?        R      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/2
 4266 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
 4385 tty4     S+     0:00 man ps
 4395 tty4     S+     0:00 pager
 4805 pts/1    S+     0:00 man ps
 4815 pts/1    S+     0:00 pager
 4827 pts/0    S+     0:00 less
 4830 pts/2    R+     0:00 ps -x
```

Practically both are equals with the exception of the latest line that represents the command executed

**Question**

- What does `-x` mean in the context of the `ps` command?

And yes, I already read both `man ps` and `ps --help all` where appears the documentation for the `x` option/parameter as follows respectively:

```
  # Approach 1
   x Lift the BSD-style "must have a tty" restriction, which is imposed upon the set of all 
     processes when some BSD-style (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality 
     setting is BSD-like.  The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the 
     set of processes selected by other means.  An alternate description is that this option 
     causes ps to list all processes owned by you (same EUID as ps), or to list all processes 
     when used together with the a option.

  # Approach 2
  x processes without controlling ttys
```

But about `-x` does not appear nothing. To be honest when the `ps` command was executed with `-x` - theoretically I expected an error because `-x` does not exist, it because `-x` is not documented.

**Extra Questions**

- If `-x` theoretically does not exist because is not documented, Why an error was not thrown?

**Note** I thought it could be a kind of default behavior for this command but it is not always true, for example it does not work with `d` - for example

- `ps -d` works
- `ps d` does **not** work - an error arises.

Well the former is documented and the latter not. So the error is expected

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/485092/931617).

Comment: The manpage also says "The POSIX and UNIX
       standards require that ps -aux print all processes owned by a
       user named x, as well as printing all processes that would be
       selected by the -a option.  If the user named x does not exist,
       this ps may interpret the command as ps aux instead and print a
       warning." It extends that behaviour to just `-x` as well.